# Using a Scanner to fill an ArrayList of objects

Tags: java, arraylist, java.util.scanner

I was trying to fill an `ArrayList` of `Ingredients`, which are objects that store the name of the ingredient (a string), the price (a double), the number of calories (an integer) and if the ingredient is vegetarian (a boolean).

Since there will be multiple ingredients, I thought I should use an `ArrayList`. How do I fill the ingredient object with the data from the scanner? This is what I have so far:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    int numberOfIngredients = s.nextInt();
    List<Ingredient> ingredientArrayList = new ArrayList<Ingredient>();
    for (int i = 0; i< numberOfIngredients; i++){
        String ingredientName = s.next();
        double pricePerOunce = s.nextDouble();
        boolean isVegetarian = s.nextBoolean();
        int numberOfCalories = s.nextInt();
        ingredientArrayList.add(ingredientName, pricePerOunce, numberOfCalories, isVegetarian);
    }// ends for loop to fill the ingredientArray
}
```

Comment: What issue are you having with the code you wrote? Also, we probably need to see at least the constructor of your `Ingredient` class to answer this.

Comment: You have a List of Ingredient objects, so you simply create and add a new Ingredient object.

Comment: To increase the speed of inserting into your `ArrayList`, pass the number of ingredients to the [`ArrayList` constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#ArrayList-int-). `new ArrayList<>(numberOfIngredients)`

Answer (score 1):

```
ingredientArrayList.add(ingredientName, pricePerOunce, numberOfCalories, isVegetarian);
```

Should be something like this

```
ingredientArrayList.add(new Ingredient(ingredientName, pricePerOunce, numberOfCalories, isVegetarian));
```

Your Ingredient class should also have constructor that takes all four attributes

You have instantiated ArrayList type of Ingredient (CLASS OBJECT) this ArrayList can only store Ingredient class object rather than individual attributes.

Comment: thanks! I don't understand what you mean by by the second part about instatiated arrayList. It says "cannot instantiate the type Ingredient". What does this mean? I thought by storing an Ingredient class object I could store the attributes of Ingredient (such as ingredient name, price per ounce, number of calories, vegetarianism).

Comment: When you create the List, you have defined the List to store Ingredient type OBJECT when you wrote List<Ingredient>. So the list can only store lists of Objects and that object must be Ingredient class object. What you have done in the first place is you are trying to store Ingredient ATTRIBUTES to List of Object. List of Object have many objects and each object have many attributes relationship

Answer (score 1):

**Ingredient** is an object, so your ArrayList is basically a List of **Ingredient** objects. To add an Ingredient object to the ArrayList, you need to add the object to the list not individual values.

Something like this:

```
ingredientArrayList.add(new Ingredient(ingredientName, pricePerOunce, numberOfCalories, isVegetarian));
```